# Service Cloud - dealing with automatic/out-of-office replies for cases

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel, email2case, casefeed

We currently have cases auto-assigned to agents with queue-based routing, with customer replies to cases automatically reopening cases and putting them back in the original queue, so they get assigned again.

If there's an automatic reply from a customer, this is triggering the rules above (as it should). Is there any easy way to deal with auto-replies from customers so the case gets closed again or does not reopen in the event that a reply is automatically generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While omni-channel queue based routing takes care of assigning the cases to available agents, the creation of case from an incoming email is still handled by ***email-to-case*** setup (*related routing email address*) and assigning the case to a queue will be handled by ***case assignment rules***.

> Is there any easy way to deal with auto-replies from customers so the
> case gets closed again or does not reopen in the event that a reply is
> automatically generated?

The approach to solve your problem should be to stop auto-reply emails from getting forwarded to the routing email address (*the one that was configured in the email-to-case setup*), so the case doesn't get reopened. This configuration (or filtering) should be done in the mailbox where you have set-up email forwarding to the routing address. For example,

- If you were using a gmail support address and had set up forwarding to the routing address, then you can apply filters in this forwarding set-up `settings` > `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` to avoid forwarding auto-response emails.
- If you were using an outlook mailbox and had set up mailbox rules to forward to the routing address, then you can set up exceptions in the rules to avoid forwarding auto-response emails.

Likewise, the configuration would differ based on which mailbox you are using for routing the incoming emails. Although, this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329628&type=1&mode=1) is about few other issues, the solution is applicable to your problem.